# Dynamically protect sheet from accidental deletion in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put a dynamic protection on the sheets in my workbook. I have many different sheets and sometimes I delete a sheet that I still need by accident.

If Cell OP15 contains a value, this means I am okay to delete the sheet to clean up my workbook. How do I create a protection for the sheets that only lets me delete it if Cell OP15 contains a value?

The closest thing I can find on the internet is something along these lines:

```
     ActiveSheet.Unprotect
     ' your vba code here
     ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Comment: I'm assuming that since you have so many sheets, you don't want to be putting code into each worksheet's `.BeforeDelete` event?

Comment: The sheets are created by using a template. So that might work, can that kind of code be added to a template? I keep list of all the names of the sheets, could I utilize that list to automate the .BeforeDelete event for each existing sheet and all new sheets?

Comment: Just to be clear, nothing guarantees that anything is safe from "accidental anything".  If this data is important, you need to have an appropriate backup strategy in place.  For example: what happens if cell OP15 "accidentally" has a value entered because someone thought they were on a different worksheet? (Then that worksheet will be accidentally deleted.)  It sounds like it may be time to move the data to MS Access for easier organizing and user interaction..

Comment: @StevenGilbert I think you can add that kind of code to a template. I was thinking it might also be good to have a msgbox that asks for verification that you want to delete the sheet. If the msgbox only appears when OP15 has a value; it would help you (or anyone else) do a double-take on if they actually want that sheet deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is pasted into the sheet code for my admin template. Cell A1 is hardcoded to say "admin template". When the template is copied Cell A1 changes to the name of the new tab.

```
     Option Explicit

     Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

     'This sub prevents acidental deletion of tab until it has been hardcoded

     If Range("a1").Value = "admin template Ticket Info" Then
     ThisWorkbook.Protect , False
     Exit Sub
     End If

     If Range("OP15").Value <> "" Then
     MsgBox "Cannot delete tab until the Onboarding details have been hardcoded."
     Exit Sub
     End If

     ThisWorkbook.Protect , True

     Application.OnTime Now, "Unprotectbook"

     End Sub
```

This is copied into one of the modules

```
     Sub UnprotectBook()

     ThisWorkbook.Unprotect

     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.BeforeDelete` does not have a cancel, so you can't stop them deleting the sheet.

from [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/prevent-worksheet-delete-without-workbook-protection/) website, you can copy the sheet, and save it from deletion that way. You could use this routine to decide if you need to save the sheet from deletion or not:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDelete()

Dim MyName As String

'Abort if no value in OP15
if [OP15].value <> "" then exit sub

'Capture the original worksheet name
MyName = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

'Rename the worksheet
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = Left(MyName, 30) + "#"

'Create a copy of the worksheet
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index)

'Name the copy to the original name
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = MyName

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. You have led me to an answer that worked for me.